# How to tell which of the associated models fails my ActiveRecord validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, validation, activerecord, error-handling

Say I have the following models:

```
class Race < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :horses
end

class Horse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :race
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Now with my REST API I'm creating a `Race` object and associate multiple horses. One of the Horses fails validation, which adds the error.

Adding an error means adding entries to `errors.details` and `errors.messages`, where `errors` is a field of the `Race` model. Both these fields are hashes, with `horses.name` as a key and details of the error(s) and error message(s) as values, respectively.

I'm looking for a way to find, which of the associated `Horse` models failed the validation so that I can provide a comprehensive error message. A reference, id, or even an index, would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
race = Race.create race_params
race.errors.messages
=> {'horses.name' => ['Can't be blank']}
race.horces[0].errors.messages
=> {'name' => ['Can't be blank']}
```

to get records with error, simply filter race.horses

```
with_error = race.horses.select{|h| h.errors.messages.present?}
index = race.horses.index( with_error[0] )
```